# Кириллица в XML

Tags: xml, php

Доброго всем дня!

Вот застрял на рускоязычной `XML`'ке.
Есть англ.вариант:

```
<messages> 
<parametr>
 <catalogue id="10" catalogname="Каталог 1"> 
 <name tovname="Товар 1"/>
 <text tovtext="текст о товаре 1"/> 
 <price internet="95" rozn="100" opt="90"/> 
 </catalogue> 
</parametr>
</messages>
```

Далее пример обработчика:

```
 foreach ($xml->parametr as $parametr)
 {
  foreach ($parametr->catalogue as $catalogue)
  {
     print ($catalogue[catalogname]);        
     print ($catalogue[id]);
     print ($catalogue->name[tovname]);
     print ($catalogue->price[internet]);
     print ($catalogue->text[tovtext]);
      }
 }
```

Все работает в англ.варианте, но вот `XML` приходит в кириллице:
т.е. хочу узнать, как будет выглядеть это:

```
print (${"каталог"}->{"продукт"}[наименование]);
```

Если в `XML` это:

```
<каталог идентификатор="10"
...
<продукт наименование="Товар 1"/>
```

Т.е. как в этом варианте принимать данные из `XML`?

Comment: Так и принимать. Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: PHP конечно срабатывает без ошибок, но приходят почему-то пустые значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В объявлении xml документа необходимо обязательно указывать кодировку, в нашем случае, это utf-8, в [Википедии написано](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), зачем это нужно.

**Код:**

```
$xmlcode = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<сообщения> 
<параметры>
 <каталог идентификатор="10" название="Каталог 1"> 
     <название>Товар 1</название>
     <текст>текст о товаре 1</текст> 
     <цена интернет="95" розница="100" опт="90" /> 
 </каталог> 
</параметры>
</сообщения>
XML;

$s = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlcode);

var_dump($s);
print "{$s->параметры->каталог->название}";
```

**Вывод:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["параметры"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["каталог"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (4) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["идентификатор"]=>
        string(2) "10"
        ["название"]=>
        string(16) "Каталог 1"
      }
      ["название"]=>
      string(12) "Товар 1"
      ["текст"]=>
      string(28) "текст о товаре 1"
      ["цена"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["интернет"]=>
          string(2) "95"
          ["розница"]=>
          string(3) "100"
          ["опт"]=>
          string(2) "90"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Товар1
```

Comment: А применение кодировки Windows-1251, что-либо может изменить в лучшую(более оптимальную по коду) сторону?
Или что-нибудь из этого Utf2Win и Win2Utf?

Comment: От Windows-1251 следует отказаться в сторону юникода - таким образом у Вас меньше шансов наткнуться на грабли. Собственно, если есть возможность, в этих xml-ках следовало бы избежать использования кириллических названий в элементах документа, хотя спецификация XMLпозволяет это делать

Comment: А можно в этом месте:
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["параметры"]=>...
поподробнее.
Извиняюсь, я первый раз с XML. Как-то всё время не пригождался.

Comment: Я использовал для парсинга xml-ки класс SimpleXML, входящий в состав php. при загрузке валидного xml он создает объектную структуру, соответствующую xml разметке и возвращает ее в переменной. Таким образом, для того, чтобы получить значение атрибута "название" элемента "каталог", необходимо обратиться к нему, как к элементу ассоциативного массива, т.е., {$сообщения->параметры->каталог['название']}.
В общем, элементы xml становятся свойствами объекта, а атрибуты нод становятся элементами ассоциативного массива, прикрепленного к конкретному свойству. Простите за сумбур

Comment: Надо попробовать, но выглядит устрашающе: string(28)
Ведь XML-ка будет содержать в себе несколько тысяч наименований.

Comment: Можно зарегистрировать свои обработчики (xml_set_*_handler) и отлавливать только интересующие ветки, остальные просто скипать.

Answer (score 2):

**messages.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<сообщения> 
<параметры>
 <каталог идентификатор="10" название="Каталог 1"> 
 <название>Товар 1<название/>
 <текст>текст о товаре 1</текст> 
 <цена интернет="95" розница="100" опт="90"/> 
 </каталог> 
</параметры>
</сообщения>
```

**messages.php**:

```
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option( $parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0 );
if(($h = fopen('messages.xml', 'r')))
{
    $data=fread($h,100000000); // хи-хи
    fclose($h);
    xml_parse($parser, $data, true); 
    var_dump( $data );
    unset($data);
}
```

**вывод**:

```
string(422) "﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<сообщения> 
<параметры>
 <каталог идентификатор="10" название="Каталог 1"> 
 <название>Товар 1<название/>
 <текст>текст о товаре 1</текст> 
 <цена интернет="95" розница="100" опт="90"/> 
 </каталог> 
</параметры>
</сообщения>
"
```

Comment: Ого! Как это? А если это XML о 5k товаров? + 20-30 параметров к нему?
Чтож за такая стринговая переменная получиться? И почему она у вас с переводами строк получилась? И что ещё второй обработчик писать, по вытаскиванию данных из этой переменной?

Comment: Простите, но эти вопросы совсем не в кассу. Я просто показал, что в XML всё с кодировкой и строками хорошо, а где именно у вас не работает - телепаты в отпуске. На всякий случай уточняю: это пример, условность, абстракция. А что такое var_dump() и как работать с результатом xml_parse() - читайте учебники, никакой второй обработчик не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Ужасно, никогда не любил за это битрикс и 1С. что весь XML у них на русском языке. Это ппц как неудобно, это используется только тут. Всегда было проще написать все на ENG, тем самым упрощается жизнь остальным разработчикам, в том числа и забугорным, если им вдруг будут нужны какие-то данные от тебя.

Перевести несколько десятков параметров и названий всегда проще, чем потом объяснять кому-то почему тут на русском написано. ИМХО.

```
<messages> 
<parametr>
 <catalogue id="10" catalogname="Каталог 1"> 
 <name tovname="Товар 1"/>
 <text tovtext="текст о товаре 1"/> 
 <price internet="95" rozn="100" opt="90"/> 
 </catalogue> 
</parametr>
</messages>
```

Это же нормальная XML'ка, читаемая, удобная. Так для справки, окажешься ты где-нибудь во франции за компом где нет русской раскладки и языка, удачи в редактировании этой XML'ки.

Да можно поставить русский язык и прочее, но редактировать это будет проблематично. Так что русский язык - это буэ... так же как и написание сайтов в кодировке win1251 вместо utf8.

Comment: Шрек, я сам вижу и понимаю, что это буэ... И сам раньше, даже интерфейс у прикладного ПО писал на латинице.
Но это же, как ты практически угодал - связка 1С + NetCat(всё разработки наших кодеров)
Поэтому 1С выгружает XML абсолтно в кирилическом варианте + кодировка win1251!
Вот я и мучаюсь, а поставивший задачу по оптимизации загрузки, язвительно намекает - "но ведь в NetCat(Мск) написали".
А процетированный тобою XML, это я себе делал для изучения принципов передачи.

Comment: А поставившему задачу я бы тоже намекнул, что проще тогда у них купить готовый продукт нежели писать свои грабли, раз он такой умный.

Comment: Купить? Речь стоит о том, нужно ли тогда платить столько денег программисту.
И вообще нужен ли он такой? Ультиматум одним словом.
В том-то и дело, что PHP-модуль от NetCat работает, но вот, типа, не устраевает их купленное, и желают, дабы проверить мою квалификацию заодно, использовать свой оптимизированный, аля эконом-класс с минимальными проверками и конкретно без всяких наворотов от NetCat. В стиле - принял данные из XML, сделал UPDATE в БД.
Ну ведь имеют, как бы, право ведь.
Предложил выгрузку в локальную БД, далее синхронизацию локальной БД с БД сайта.
Отложили в долгий ящик.

Comment: иногда проще купить готовое нежели писать своё.

Я вот иногда своему начальству предлагаю такие идеи. Ибо реально иногда проще купить.

Answer (score 0):

> В объявлении xml документа необходимо обязательно указывать кодировку, в нашем случае, это utf-8

Всё! Задачу решил! Не только указанием кодировки XML в коде "header('...charset...)", но и + перекодировки самого PHP. (и это ещё только локально, что ещё ждёт на серваке у хостера не известно...)

Вот блин кириллица, и кто её продвигает?

Comment: Те, кто до сих пор не знает, что юникод - это наше все)

Comment: Битрикс её продвигает и 1С - монополисты среди мусорного бака! Столько хлама в коде, как они сами там разбираются!