# Поиск русских XML тегов в документе

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, xml

Добрый день.
Есть документ XML, который парсится со стороннего ресурса и преобразовывается в обычный html.
**В этом документе все XML теги на русском языке.**

Большинство тегов заранее известны и они заменяются на обычные html.
Но часто есть неизвестные теги которые нужно залогировать, что бы в дальнейшем обрабатывать.

Мучаюсь второй день - не могу составить регулярку которая в тексте будет находить xml теги и складывать их в отдельный документ.

**Пример тегов которые могут быть:**

- <тег>текст внутри тега< /тег>
- <тег атрибут="значение" второй_атрибут="второе_значение">текст внутри тега
- <тег_тегович />
- <тег />
- <тег атрибут="значение" />

Помогите пожалуйста с решением :)
Буду признателен.

Comment: Функция simplexml_load_file() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-string.php должна работать и с русскими тегами. Файл в кодировке UTF-8 должен быть.

Comment: Возможно дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134476/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открывающиеся теги целиком:

```
/<[A-ZА-ЯЁ_][^>]*>/i
```

Только имена открывающихся тегов - взять первую группу или отрезать первый символ:

```
/<([A-ZА-ЯЁ_]+)/i
```

Открывающиеся и закрывающиеся теги целиком:

```
/<\/?[A-ZА-ЯЁ_][^>]*>/i
```

Comment: Почему-то не выходит.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

`
<?php
$text = '<text xml:id="x9tmorcwb403eujizef5m52vkb">
        <шапка xml:id="x9x4njabpdv6cc6bfcge0wr30v" lid="xcyixrgqxdpj06i7h6cki26yh8">
  Текст
        </шапка>
    </text>';

$pattern = '/<[A-ZА-ЯЁ_][^>]*>/gi';
preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$out,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out);
?>
`

Comment: @DubovikYuriy, `PREG_SET_ORDER` попробуй. А вообще, не знаю. На js работает: `text = '<text xml:id="x9tmorcwb403eujizef5m52vkb"> <шапка xml:id="x9x4njabpdv6cc6bfcge0wr30v" lid="xcyixrgqxdpj06i7h6cki26yh8"> Текст </шапка> </text>';
text.match(/<[A-ZА-ЯЁ_][^>]*>/gi)` - получается `["<text xml:id="x9tmorcwb403eujizef5m52vkb">", "<шапка xml:id="x9x4njabpdv6cc6bfcge0wr30v" lid="xcyixrgqxdpj06i7h6cki26yh8">"]`

Comment: @DubovikYuriy, `WARNING preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'g' on line number 6`

Comment: Так и есть. Убрал g - все заработало. Спасибо большое за помощь.